# No overload for method move

Tags: c#, process, system, move

So basically, I have a process that starts from user input in a textbox.
But one of the arguments in the process contains a folder which the user has but has the be renamed. and only after it would be renamed it would start the process. So I got.

```
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"{0}\@JonzieMegaModPack"))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
            startInfo.Arguments =
                string.Format(@"-window -useBE {1} -mod={0}\@CBA_A3", textBox2.Text, textBox3);
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.Move(@"{0}\@Jonzie Mega Mod Pack", @"{0}\@JonzieMegaModPack", textBox2.Text);
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
            startInfo.Arguments =
                string.Format(@"-window -useBE {1} -mod={0}\@CBA_A3", textBox2.Text, textBox3);
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
```

But in the `else` part, with `Directory.Move`
I get the error saying: no overload for method 'Move' takes 3 arguments.
I'm guessing because of the komma at then end for the {0}.

Comment: Well yes, there are no overloads of [`Directory.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx) with three parameters. What did you expect that call to do? How do you expect it to *use* all three arguments? Perhaps you mean to call `string.Format`? (It seems likely, as I doubt that you've actually got a directory called `{0}`.)

Comment: The `{0}`'s are used for `string.Format()`. It is missing somewhere from your code, perhaps.

Comment: The {0} is the start of a directory. For me its e:\Aaron\Addons which then continues with whats behind the {0}. then the , textbox2.text should lead to that {0} shouldnt it?

Comment: @AaronKek: No, absolutely not. You can't just use string formatting in arbitrary method calls like that. Methods like `Console.WriteLine` *explicitly* support string formatting - it's not just implicit on every call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're calling [`Directory.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx), which only has one overload, with two string parameters. It's not clear why/how you expected that to work.

I suspect you're missing calls to `string.Format`, e.g.

```
string source = string.Format(@"{0}\@Jonzie Mega Mod Pack", textBox2.Text);
string destination = string.Format(@"{0}\@JonzieMegaModPack", textBox2.Text);
Directory.Move(source, destination);
```

Or in C# 6 you could use string interpolation:

```
string source = $@"{textBox2.Text}\@Jonzie Mega Mod Pack";
string destination = $@"{textBox2.Text}\@JonzieMegaModPack";
Directory.Move(source, destination);
```

I would recommend using `Path.Combine` instead though:

```
string source = Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, "@Jonzie Mega Mod Pack");
string destination = Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, "@JonzieMegaModPack");
Directory.Move(source, destination);
```

Comment: Yeah it does have @ symbols in the dirs. The @ shows its a modpack for a game.

Comment: @AaronKek: Okay, will remove that last bit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works, but now when I click the button, it seems to skip the if part. it goes straight to else?

Comment: @AaronKek: Well yes, you've got the same problem there as well - do you actually expect a directory called `"{0}\@JonzieMegaModPack"` to exist? No - you need `string.Format` or `Path.Combine` again. Basically, you need to stop assuming that string formatting is going to happen implicitly everywhere. (In this case you didn't even provide a value to replace the `{0}`...)

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that. You think you can put the string.Format code in your answer too? I think after that I should understand it.

Comment: @AaronKek: Well I'd imagine it's exactly the same as the `string.Format` code for `destination`, which again should be `Path.Combine`. You should probably just declare `destination` *before* your `if` block and use `if (Directory.Exists(destination)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

This method only has one signature which is `Directory.Move(string, string)`

You are trying to call it with 3 arguments...which the signature does not exist. Have a look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx).

I think you are trying to have one of your arguments as string.Format(), and you have not made it clear...perhaps you are using ReSharper?